# How to Split Codeigniter pseudo variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, benchmarking

How can I remove file size unit from {memory_usage} pseudo variable?
For example "2.26MB -> 2.26"

I use this way :

```
$mem = $this->benchmark->memory_usage();
echo substr($mem, 0, -2);
```

But It does not work. The result is :
"{memory_usag"

Comment: Clearly you don't have what you expect to have as the return value of that function (which you didn't include). Also i cannot understand what you mean by "pseudo variable" in this context. You're simply dealing with a string return value of `{memory_usage}`.

Comment: The problem with using that benchmark method is that it doesn't return the value. It only returns a placeholder to be used in a view (the view engine replaces it with the memory usage when it's rendered). Imho, it's a very odd method. You'll probably need to implement that function yourself to be able to modify the value. Check out [memory_get_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and [memory_get_peak_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, memory_usage will return "2.26MB" and you want "2.26". If you know that the unit will always be 2 characters you could do it like this:

```
$mem = "2.26MB";
substr($mem, -2); // returns "2.26"
```

In your example:

```
substr($mem, 0, -2);
```

You are setting the offset position to 0 in the second argument, which starts the substring at the beginning of `$mem`, then you are creating a substring that is -2 characters in length.

Comment: In their code they have `echo substr($mem, 0, -2);` which gives `"{memory_usag"`.  So it more looks like where they get it from than how to remove the last 2 chars.

Comment: Then we need to know more about `$this->benchmark->memory_usage()`

Comment: That method is a CodeIgniter method that only returns a placeholder to be used in a view. It doesn't return the actual value itself.

Comment: Benchmark class has two methods, "elapsed_time()" that displays total execution time and "memory_usage()" function that displays memory consumption for each page load. Another way to display these variables are {elapsed_time} and {memory_usage}.

Comment: When I use the "gettype" method, it returns "string", but its behavior is not like a "string".

Comment: It seems like it is acting as a string, the string is "{memory_usage}", but you are expecting the string to be "2.26MB".